# Azure devops yaml pipeline how to reset a parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm using parameters within my yaml pipeline which are set on runtime by the user. For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: StartAfterDeployment
    displayName: 'Start after deployment'
    type: boolean
    default: true
```

When the pipeline has ran successfully and (and the user selected false), and the user choose "Run new" on that deployment. The option is selected false instead of the default true.

Is it possible to "reset" the parameters to the default settings when choosing the Run new option or to disable completely the run rew option?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to "reset" the parameters to the default settings when
> choosing the Run new option or to disable completely the run rew
> option?

Yes, you can 'reset' the settings via default parameter settings. But on that page, it will use the same configuration as this pipeline run.

The 'run new' here is actually similar to 'rerun'. It's a 'sugar pill' that helps you not have to spend time ticking the same settings when you run it again when you have a lot of configuration settings.

If you want to reset the settings to default, it is also easy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not solving the issue. We have very sophisticated pipelines with manual input values what you don't want to be re-used. The user just clicks on run new and there they are again. The value must be cleared